# Tensorflow flattened scalar summary from vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Given a variable-length vector placeholder, how can I "flatten" this information to use in a scalar summary? The vector is computed outside of a tensorflow graph. A solution could look like an implementation of the function `scalars_from_vector` as below:

```
v_foo = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None), name="vector_of_foo")
tf.summary.scalars_from_vector("info/foo", v_foo)
```